# Android app testing: Appium does not launch the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I'm testing an android app with Appium, but I can't start the inspector because shortly after pressing start session, 
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCykk.png) appears.
I also add screenshots of the project where you can clearly see the [package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOOcV.png). I have tried many combinations of capabilities but Appium continues with the same problem.

[Here is Appium configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpGNZ.png)
I tried to make other attempts:
Example:
pkg: net.phunehehe.foocam
activity: MainActivity
or
pkg: net.phunehehe
activity: net.phunehehe.foocam.MainActivity

Finally, please note that Appium works fine on other applications.
Here's the [link](https://github.com/phunehehe/foocam/tree/a9dfae7b2506b987d9823312c563aab50e41ca4a) of the repository.

Comment: You have to add path of your .apk file as "app" in desired capabilities. Even after adding app in your capabilities if you are not able to launch application, remove activity from desired capabilities and try again.

Comment: Is your app already installed in your device? How did you get app Activity and package?